# Alamofire NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.sharedManager.isEnabled = true , Use of Unresolved Identifier

Tags: swift, alamofire

Alamofires networking tool AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator is not working properly. When I put my code,  `NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.sharedManager.isEnabled = true`
I get use of unresolved Identifier. I don't understand why it does not exist, maybe with the new Xcode update, but honestly not sure why. [Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV4tI.png)

Comment: Do you have the library installed and imported into the file correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and wanted to avoid additional import statements inside AppDelegate but ended up doing it after linking frameworks did not succeed:

```swift
import AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator
```

Used environment:
xCode 7.3, Swift 2, Cocoapods: 0.39.0, AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator (1.0.1)